# how to find row number of first non zero value in a column in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `T1` with columns `countryid, stateid, Value`.

I need row number of `stateid` value which has the first non-zero value for every country. Data in the table is ordered by `CountryId ASC, StateId ASC`.

```
(Countryid, Stateid, Value)
(1, 11, 0)
(1, 12, 1)
(1, 13, 0)
(2, 21, 0)
(2, 22, 0)
(2, 23, 1)
(3, 31, 0)
(3, 32, 10)
(3, 33, 0)
(3, 34, 20)
```

I need output like below.

- for countryid 1, row number I need as output should be 2.
- for countryid 2, row number I need as output should be 3.
- for countryid 3, row number I need as output should be 2.

Comment: How do you know you've got "every" country accounted for?

Comment: Can you have multiple non-zero values per country? What constitutes "first" non-zero value? Shall we assume we're sorting by StateId?

Comment: yes , i can have multiple non-zero values per country

Comment: How do you define "first"? The lowest stateid? The highest? Some information in the table you haven't shown? Some information that can't be inferred from the data in the table?

Comment: There is no such thing as "row number" here unless you can define one based on the data. A table is otherwise an unordered bag of rows ([see #3 here](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/t-sql-tuesday-56-sql-server-assumptions/)). So, let's try again: Do you want the lowest `stateid` with a non-zero `value`? What if 3/34 was inserted or appears "before" 3/32? What then?

Comment: CountryId and StateId are ordered in ascending. So T1 will always have 3/34 after 3/32. and yes i wan the lowest stateid with non-zero value.

Answer (score 2):

Can be done using partitions

```
;With CTE_T1 As
(
   Select 
       CountryID, StateID, Value, 
       Row_Number Over (Partition By CountryID Order By Value) As RK
   From 
       T1 
   Where 
       IsNull(Values, 0) <> 0
)
Select * 
From CTE_T1 
Where RK = 1
```

The order by clause in the partition will be used to choose the record if there are more than one non zero values.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH FormattedT1 AS
(
    SELECT Countryid, Stateid, Value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Countryid ORDER BY ...) AS num
    FROM T1
    WHERE Value > 0
)
SELECT Countryid, Stateid, Value
FROM FormattedT1
WHERE num = 1
```

Comment: use the columns that you want to order by. This will depend on the business logic. Else just add countryid to negate the effect.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing from required result set, as stated in the OP, the following query returns the desired 'row number' per `countryid`:

```
SELECT countryid, MIN(rn) AS rn
FROM (
   SELECT *,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY countryid 
                             ORDER BY stateid) AS rn
   FROM T1 ) t
WHERE Value <> 0
GROUP BY countryid
```

So, my guess is that to each record of `T1` a row number is assigned *within each `countryid` partition*. Record with *lowest* `stateid` within a `countryid` partition has `row number = 1`,  next record has `row number = 2`, etc.

Output based on sample data of OP:

```
countryid   rn
---------------
1           2
2           3
3           2
```